# initialising int from char string

Tags: c++, casting, char

```
unsigned int someInt = 'MPG3';
```

someInt will now hold a value of 1297106739. I always thought the compiler would complain if more than 1 character was within single quotes. I would like to know how the compiler is getting this value, and if it's possible to retrieve the char value.

```
char someChar = someInt;
char someChar = (char)someInt;
```

They don't work.

Comment: About the second part of the question: Are you aware that a single char variable can´t hold 4 chars (or anything as big as 4 chars)?

Comment: good point. Is there a quicker way to read it into a char array than bitshifting for each individual character?

Comment: `(char *)(&someInt)` (but there is no \0, and remember that while it´s allowed everywhere, the value of someInt itself is implementation-defined)